# Order the parameters as mentioned in the template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

When you create stacks in the console, the console lists input parameters in alphabetical order by their logical IDs. There is way to customize the order using Interface.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudformation-interface.html

But is there any way to order the parameters as mentioned in the template?

Comment: What's wrong with using `AWS::CloudFormation::Interface`? This is the only way to order the parameters.

Comment: The template becomes lengthy and difficult to maintain. The default order should be same as mentioned in template and there should be a parameter to sort (for those who really need it).

Comment: Sadly there is no other way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `AWS::CloudFormation::Interface` which allows you to set the order, and also additionally you can group your parameters together. The order you specify the parameters in the `Parameters` list, will be the order they appear in the console.

Example below, taken from [the aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudformation-interface.html)

```yaml
Metadata: 
  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface: 
    ParameterGroups: 
      - 
        Label: 
          default: "Network Configuration"
        Parameters: 
          - VPCID
          - SubnetId
          - SecurityGroupID
      - 
        Label: 
          default: "Amazon EC2 Configuration"
        Parameters: 
          - InstanceType
          - KeyName
    ParameterLabels: 
      VPCID: 
        default: "Which VPC should this be deployed to?"
```